# Dynamic paged content - how can I make sure links lead back to the same content?

Tags: url, seo

Say I have a series of posts which are paged starting with the newest posts on the first page, and ending with the oldest posts.

I'm trying to implement the paging in such a way as to allow for the following two things:

i) When someone copies the url and sends it to someone else, they will get the same results, even if it is 6 months later and there have been hundreds of posts added in the interim.

ii) When search engines index the content, links from search results will bring back the content that was indexed, even if the content that was on page 3 when it was indexed is now on page 7.

So to try and explain clearly. If I were to implement paging in the simplest way, I might have URL's looking something like this:

www.foobar.com/foo?page=7

but if someone takes that link and sends it to someone, page 7 could well have completely different content by the time the person comes to look at it. Likewise, the content that was indexed by a search engine would quickly become out of date.

I thought of having an id identify the first post in that particular page in the URL, instead of the page number. But then I run into issues of how to do the paging when someone comes in from that link, it becomes a bit problematic.

Or perhaps I should just forget these issues, provide permalinks to the posts themselves, and if users send the url to people instead of the permalinks then that's their lookout. I would prefer to cover these two scenarios though, if there is a neat way to do it.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We've looked at the way other people deal with this, and that is to allow people to navigate through posts by month and year rather than by page.

So instead of the navigation having page 1, page 2 etc...

We will have June 2013, May 2013

and the URL will look something like:
www.foobar.com/foo/2013/6

This is what wordpress/blogger seem to do.